# Design: GraphicManager, TexturesPool, Texture

Tags: c++, oop

I have system in which present class sigleton GraphicManager, class TexturePool and class Texture.

Texture have some subtles in creation. Then it constructing itself they use DirectX stuff from GraphicManager and some d3d constants. Now i use CreateInstance method and private cons in Texture class, but as for me its not goot what Texture now so much about real engine, may be better to build it from GraphicManager? Do i need use for it friend function or may be else approach?

Comment: As a first Start accepting some answers, I cannot believe out of 10 Questions you asked that atleast answer was not helpful to you.

Comment: Ok, i just didnt know about this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really couldn't understand your question, but I'll try to give you some tips. It's ok if you use Singleton in GraphicManager or in TexturePool, but you have to be careful, because singleton allows you to use the unique instance even when you shouldn't. Singleton can make the code easier to type, but a quite dangerous too. As I could understand you are now using Singleton in Texture class, but I think that in your system you can have more than one Texture, so it doesn't make sense. However, you can create a method in your TexturePool class to load a texture from a image file. Something like:

```
Texture* TexturePool::loadTexture(std::string fileName);
```

Then, anything that you need to use to create a texture, you should get from GraphicsManager's unique instance. I hope this could be useful for you.